# Finding Page Number of specific record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My users table, the table structure is:

```
ID UserName
 1   AAA
 4   BBB
 7   CCC
 ........
 ........
```

where ID is a Primary Key and Identity field.

Assume that PageSize is 10, and I want to `find the page number for the ID 43`. Is there any way to find the ID (43) in which page?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 10
DECLARE @Order DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @UserID INT = 1

SET @Order = (  SELECT  OrderNo
                FROM
                    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID) AS OrderNo
                     FROM   Users
                    ) AS U
                WHERE U.UserID = @UserID
             )

SELECT @UserID AS UserID, CEILING(@Order/@PageSize) PageNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Row_Number](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308281/How-to-Use-ROW-NUMBER-to-Enumerate-and-Partition-R) with partition option you can achieve this.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID) AS OrderNo, *
                     FROM   Users
```

Now you simple give where condition with page size to find out the page no. In your case, simple query give the result without partition option.

```
Declare @userid int =  43,    @PageSize int = 10

;with cte as
(
  SELECT  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID) AS OrderNo, *
  FROM   Users 
)                     

Select 
      CEILING(OrderNo/@PageSize) PageNo 
FROM 
       cte where userID = @UserID
```

Row_number with Partition option. If you want to re-order on another column then ,

```
;with cte as
    (
      SELECT  
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY UserID ) AS OrderNo, *
      FROM   Users 
    )           
Select 
          CEILING(OrderNo/@PageSize) PageNo 
    FROM 
           cte where userID = @UserID
```

Comment: Where you used Partition in about query?

Comment: tnx , please check the updated answer. partition by is used to re-order based on another column like company have userid, so we re-order/reset company wise userid.